# Fourier Transform should contradict that inner-product spaces have countably many non-trivial Fourier components

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

In Erwin Kreyszig's "Introduction to Functional Analysis", there is a Lemma 3.5-3 that states that given an orthonormal family $(e_\kappa)$, $\kappa\in I$, then any $x$ in our inner-product space $X$ has at most countably many nontrivial Fourier coefficients $\langle x,e_\kappa\rangle$. I understand the proof of this statement using Bessel's inequality.

I am confused, however, because I thought that the Fourier transform represents uncountably many Fourier components in $L^2$, which in general are nontrivial. Is there a difference between the frequency components of a function, which can be expressed as an uncountable family of orthonormal vectors, and the spaces described in the lemma? I would appreciate any help.

Edit: it appears that a discussion of this issue was done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951827/why-coefficients-of-fourier-series-are-countable-though-the-initial-periodic-fu), but many of these concepts went right over my head. Is there a simpler description of what they are saying?

Comment: note that when you talk about the Fourier transform on the real line, the frequencies are not integrable so do not actually belong to $L^2(\mathbb R)$ and are not a basis or orthonormal or anything in this context; you can definitely get a basis (a standard one is given by Hermite Polynomials mollified by the Gaussian to make them square-integrable on the line) and that is countable and the usual results apply

Comment: @Conrad Thank you so much, this has been bothering me for sooo long.

Comment: note also that the Fourier transform while an isomorphism of $L^2$ is global (in other words unless you specify smooth subclasses of $L^2$ which are generally "small", you cannot really talk about its value at a point as that is not well defined in $L^2$ again unless you are on a small subclass like continuous functions etc; so when we talk about Fourier transform we have to be careful - usually we consider the Fourier transform of "nice" functions and then it makes sense to talk about $\hat {f}(y)$ but when we look at it as an $L^2$ operator it makes sense only to talk about $\hat f$